# valueerror invalid model reference, how can i reference correctly

Tags: python, django, orm

I had to change a number of my ManyToMany relations to reference a string instead of importing the model into the file so to avoid a number of circular importing errors.

but when trying to run, now I am getting this error.

```
ValueError: Invalid model reference 'dsi.administration.libraries.Library'. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.
```

I don't know what would be the best way to reference this and I'd love to get anyone's input on this.

the reference in question

```
    models.ManyToManyField("dsi.administration.libraries.Library", verbose_name='library choices')
```

settings.py installed modules

```
SHARED_APPS = (
    "storages",
    "django_tenants",  # mandatory
    'dsi.events.event',
    'dsi.administration.libraries',
    'dsi.account'
)
```

the app folder structure

```
├── dsi
│   ├── account
│   │   ├──__init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   ├── events
│   │   ├── event
|   │   │   ├── __init__.py
|   │   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├──__init__.py
│   ├── administration
│   │   ├── libraries
|   │   │   ├── __init__.py
|   │   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── general
|   │   │   ├── __init__.py
|   │   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── settings.py
├── manage.py
```

Comment: Does your `libraries` module contains an `apps.py`?

Comment: yes its name = 'dsi.administration.libraries'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> To refer to models defined in another application, you can explicitly
> specify a model with the full application *label*.

The app label (unless specified in the app config) is by default the *last* part of the full python path (the app name) to the app, so `libraries`, not <s>`dsi.administration.libraries.Library`</s>. If you have an `AppConfig`, then the `AppConfig` will specify the name of the app, such `AppConfig` can look like:

```
# dsi/administration/libraries/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class AppNameConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'dsi.administration.libraries'
```

Therefore here the label would be `libraries`. If you thus found the label of the app, you should specify the model with `app_label.Library`, so if the `app_label` is equal to `libraries`, then it is:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model)
    models.ManyToManyField(
        'libraries.Library',
        verbose_name='library choices'
    )
```

Comment: from django.apps import AppConfig


class LibrariesConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'dsi.administration.libraries'

Comment: this is what I have as the app config name.  so it's confusing.

Comment: @Ebolasudan Is there any `label` specified in there? If not take the last part of the `name` (`name` is the full python path to the app).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: aarrgghhh, yes, confused the two (copy-paste but without updating it properly). Thanks!

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat could you show an example of what you are referencing? I'm still learning

Comment: @Ebolasudan: it is the `label` of the `AppNameConfig` that should be set, if you specify a `name = '...'` in the `AppConfig`, then it will use the last part of the dot separated name, so in this case `libraries`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ahhh it just clicked, its under name not label

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem edited your answer, hope you don't mind ;)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: not at all, what a mistake :(, thanks!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so class LibrariesConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'dsi.events.event'
    label = 'event'

Comment: @Ebolasudan: if you use `event`, then yes. But if that is the `LibrariesAppConfig`, the question is what `EventAppConfig` should do. I would advise to keep the app names as they are, unless there is a good reason to change.

Comment: its allowed me to move past the actual error. by adding the label to the app config and referencing it as such, the reference i used in the last comment was from a diff module that i was updating and didnt change the rest of the info. sorry for the confusion. @WillemVanOnsem thank you. im trying to refactor the code now and see what errors it gives me once the labels are all correct if any.